# Mysterious blank space in html grid

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to place 3 elements in a grid, I am getting a bunch of white space between the image element and the h1 element and I'm unsure why.
If I replace the image element with another h1 element the whitespace disappers. Any thoughts?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            .first-column {
            grid-column:1;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          .second-column {
            grid-column:2;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          .third-column {
            grid-column:3;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          div.container-button-grid {
            margin: 20 auto;
            width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            display:grid;
            grid-column-gap:0px;
          }

          h1 {
              font-size: 30px;
              margin:0 0;
              padding:0px 0px;
              background:lightgreen;
          }

          img {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background:red;
          }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-button-grid">
            <img class="first-column" src="../images/Logo.png"></img>
            <h1 class="second-column">Test</h1>
            <button class="third-column" type="button" class="button"> 
                Reviews
            </button>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Grid` use equal space for the number of grids you define.
- you need to give value to `grid-template-columns` to give specific
  width to the column.
- You need to set `grid-template-columns` in
  `.div.container-button-grid`.
- remove `</img>` as `img` tag is self closing tag.

```css
.first-column {
            grid-column:1;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          .second-column {
            grid-column:2;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          .third-column {
            grid-column:3;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          div.container-button-grid {
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            display:grid;
            grid-column-gap:0px;
            grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr 1fr; /* change 40px as per your requirement */
          }

          h1 {
              font-size: 30px;
              margin:0 0;
              padding:0px 0px;
              background:lightgreen;
          }

          img {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background:red;
          }
```

```html
<div class="container-button-grid">
  <img class="first-column" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  <h1 class="second-column">Test</h1>
  <button class="third-column" type="button" class="button"> 
      Reviews
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Zuber. Could you explain how the Grid causes each element to take up equal space, it doesn't look like by default that the elements take up equal space, they seem to take up what they want!

Comment: @blake_griffin its because of the `fr` unit. Fr is a fractional unit and `1fr` is for 1 part of the available space.

Answer (score 1):

Your `img` has fixed `width`. If you won't specify it in css, there will be no gap.

```css
.first-column {
            grid-column:1;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          .second-column {
            grid-column:2;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          .third-column {
            grid-column:3;
            grid-row:1;
          }

          div.container-button-grid {
            margin: 20 auto;
            width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            display:grid;
            grid-column-gap:0px;
          }

          h1 {
              font-size: 30px;
              margin:0 0;
              padding:0px 0px;
              background:lightgreen;
          }

          img {
            /*width: 40px;*/
            height: 40px;
            background:red;
          }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-button-grid">
            <img class="first-column" src="../images/Logo.png" alt="" />
            <h1 class="second-column">Test</h1>
            <button class="third-column" type="button" class="button"> 
                Reviews
            </button>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want `img` to leave with specific sizes, wrap it with `div` for example.

```css
.first-column {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.second-column {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.third-column {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

div.container-button-grid {
  margin: 20 auto;
  width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  /*background: red;*/
}

.img-wrapper {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-button-grid">
    <div class="img-wrapper first-column">
      <img class="" src="../images/Logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <h1 class="second-column">Test</h1>
    <button class="third-column" type="button" class="button"> 
      Reviews
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

PS Also remove `</img>` tag, you use it like this `<img class="first-column" src="../images/Logo.png" alt="" />`. Add `alt` into it